# Magento product edit screen, categories not appearing

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento store (ver 1.5.1.0) with a lot of categories, the categories have been added using the following category duplication script -

```
<?php
if(!is_numeric($_GET['id']))die('Please specify a category ID');

$catId = $_GET['id'];

$xml = simplexml_load_file('app/etc/local.xml');
$host = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->host;
$username = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->username;
$password = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->password;
$dbname = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->dbname; 
$res = mysql_pconnect($host, $username, $password);   
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$catsDone = 0;
duplicate_entity($catId);
echo $catsDone . ' Categories duplicated.';

function duplicate_entity($id, $parent_id = null){
    global $catsDone;


    // Grab category to copy
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity WHERE entity_id = " . $id;
    $query_entity = mysql_query($sql);

    $entity = mysql_fetch_object($query_entity);

    if(!$parent_id)$parent_id = $entity->parent_id;

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO catalog_category_entity (entity_type_id, attribute_set_id, parent_id, created_at, updated_at, path, position, level, children_count)
                        VALUES ({$entity->entity_type_id}, {$entity->attribute_set_id}, {$parent_id}, NOW(), NOW(), '', {$entity->position}, {$entity->level}, {$entity->children_count})");
    $newEntityId = mysql_insert_id();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT path FROM catalog_category_entity WHERE entity_id = " . $parent_id);
    $parent = mysql_fetch_object($query);
    $path = $parent->path . '/' . $newEntityId;

    mysql_query("UPDATE catalog_category_entity SET path='". $path."' WHERE entity_id=". $newEntityId);

    foreach(array('datetime', 'decimal', 'int', 'text', 'varchar') as $dataType){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_".$dataType."
                WHERE entity_id=" . $entity->entity_id;
                //die($sql);
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($value = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO catalog_category_entity_".$dataType." (entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
                            VALUES ({$value->entity_type_id}, {$value->attribute_id}, {$value->store_id}, {$newEntityId}, '{$value->value}')");
        }
    }

    $sql = "SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_category_entity WHERE parent_id = " . $id;
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($entity = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
        duplicate_entity($entity->entity_id, $newEntityId);
    }
    $catsDone++;
}
?>
```

The categories appear fine in the category tree, front end, etc, however on the product edit screen on the category edit tab, I can only see the default category?

Comment: Looks like javascript issue, do you see any javascript error in your firebug console?

Answer (score 3):

Your "children_count" column in catalog_category_entity is probably incorrect. I had the same problem.

Run this:

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity SET children_count = "1" WHERE children_count < 1;
```

Reference / more info: http://zaclee.net/magento/errors-magento/magento-product-edit-only-shows-default-category

Answer (score 1):

Your import script didn't cover all the table columns of "catalog_category_entity" table. Basically, you forgot to update "level" and "children_count" rows. [Here's how you can fix this](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/solving-problems-with-category-tree-database-information/).

Oh, and I forgot. Zachary's script linked here is also bad. It does not fix the problem, but merely mask it and leave it to JavaScript to "chew it up". The script I linked will set everything up correctly.

Comment: I understand how my solution could 'mask' the problem (although my solution leads to no issues), but can you explain the bit about JavaScript 'chewing it up'? No idea what that means and am genuinely curious.